# Python Ansible API Executes command only in Control nodes not in Remote nodes

Tags: python, ansible

I am fairly new to using python ansible API,I have used the example code given in the Ansible API documentation.I am trying to run a simple command 'ls' using command module on multiple nodes,As you can see from the output,it looks like it didn't exactly executed the command on the remote nodes, instead it executed it on the control node from where I am running the script ,Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

## Playbook

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import shutil
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
import ansible.constants as C

#import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    """A sample callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in

    If you want to collect all results into a single object for processing at
    the end of the execution, look into utilizing the ``json`` callback plugin
    or writing your own custom callback plugin
    """
    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        """Print a json representation of the result

        This method could store the result in an instance attribute for retrieval later
        """
        host = result._host
        print(json.dumps({host.name: result._result}, indent=4))
# since API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set, named tuple 'fakes' the args parsing options object
Options = namedtuple('Options', ['connection', 'module_path', 'forks', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check', 'diff'])
options = Options(connection='local', module_path=['/to/mymodules'], forks=10, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False, diff=False)

# initialize needed objects
loader = DataLoader() # Takes care of finding and reading yaml, json and ini files
passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

# Instantiate our ResultCallback for handling results as they come in. Ansible expects this to be one of its main display outlets
results_callback = ResultCallback()

# create inventory, use path to host config file as source or hosts in a comma separated string
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=['hosts_all'])

# variable manager takes care of merging all the different sources to give you a unifed view of variables available in each context
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

# create datastructure that represents our play, including tasks, this is basically what our YAML loader does internally.
play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = 'navihosts',
        gather_facts = 'no',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='command', args='hostname'), register='shell_out'),
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))
         ]
    )


play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)

# Run it - instantiate task queue manager, which takes care of forking and setting up all objects to iterate over host list and tasks
tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
              inventory=inventory,
              variable_manager=variable_manager,
              loader=loader,
              options=options,
              passwords=passwords,
              stdout_callback=results_callback,  # Use our custom callback instead of the ``default`` callback plugin, which prints to stdout
          )
    result = tqm.run(play) # most interesting data for a play is actually sent to the callback's methods
finally:
    # we always need to cleanup child procs and the structres we use to communicate with them
    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()

    # Remove ansible tmpdir
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
```

## Inventory file

```
[navihosts]
server1.example.com
rabbitmq-2
diyvb2
```

## Output

```
{
    "server1.example.com": {
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "changed": true,
        "end": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.299643",
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "stdout": "server1.example.com",
        "cmd": [
            "hostname"
        ],
        "start": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.282674",
        "delta": "0:00:00.016969",
        "stderr": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "_raw_params": "hostname",
                "removes": null,
                "argv": null,
                "warn": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "stdin": null
            }
        },
        "stdout_lines": [
            "server1.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
{
    "diyvb2": {
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "changed": true,
        "end": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.318774",
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "stdout": "server1.example.com",
        "cmd": [
            "hostname"
        ],
        "start": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.257133",
        "delta": "0:00:00.061641",
        "stderr": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "_raw_params": "hostname",
                "removes": null,
                "argv": null,
                "warn": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "stdin": null
            }
        },
        "stdout_lines": [
            "server1.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
{
    "rabbitmq-2": {
        "_ansible_parsed": true,
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "changed": true,
        "end": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.337210",
        "_ansible_no_log": false,
        "stdout": "server1.example.com",
        "cmd": [
            "hostname"
        ],
        "start": "2019-05-04 18:30:33.289134",
        "delta": "0:00:00.048076",
        "stderr": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "_raw_params": "hostname",
                "removes": null,
                "argv": null,
                "warn": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "stdin": null
            }
        },
        "stdout_lines": [
            "server1.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
{
    "server1.example.com": {
        "msg": "server1.example.com",
        "changed": false,
        "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false
    }
}
{
    "rabbitmq-2": {
        "msg": "server1.example.com",
        "changed": false,
        "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false
    }
}
{
    "diyvb2": {
        "msg": "server1.example.com",
        "changed": false,
        "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
        "_ansible_no_log": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the `hostname` command on your remote hosts:

```py
dict(action=dict(module='command', args='hostname'), register='shell_out'),
```

However, you are explicitly using the `local` connection plugin:

```py
options = Options(connection='local',
                  module_path=['/to/mymodules'],
                  forks=10,
                  become=None,
                  become_method=None,
                  become_user=None,
                  check=False,
                  diff=False)
```

This means that Ansible will simply run everything locally, rather than connecting to any remote hosts. That's why in your output you always see a single hostname:

```
    "stdout": "server1.example.com",
    ...
    "stdout": "server1.example.com",
    ...
    "stdout": "server1.example.com",
```

You probably want to set `connection='ssh'`:

```py
options = Options(connection='local',
                  module_path=['/to/mymodules'],
                  forks=10,
                  become=None,
                  become_method=None,
                  become_user=None,
                  check=False,
                  diff=False)
```

With that change, and an inventory suitable for my environment, the code you have presented works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote a callback plugin.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins

What you probably want to write is a module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html

Comment: The poster did **not** write a callback plugin.  They wrote an Ansible playbook in Python.  They are **using** a callback module as part of their solution.